# DIR loop over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

logging with ssh to remote server using

```
ssh user@01.01.03.04 -i /path/to/ppk.key
```

then running

```
[user@ip-01-01-03.04 ~]$ sudo su - 
[root@ip-01-01-03.04 ~]# for curdir in $(dir /); do echo "fil=$curdir" ; done
```

Effectively lists all root directories:

```
fil=bin
fil=dev
fil=lib
```

But trying to do it from remote to retrieve result locally is getting tricky to me:

```
ssh user@01.01.03.04 -i /drives/c/pass/keys/MY.ppk "sudo -i -u root bash -c 'for curdir in \$(dir \/); do echo "fil=$curdir" ; done'"
```

give:

```
fil=var
fil=var
fil=var 
(...)
```

and

```
ssh user@01.01.03.04 -i /drives/c/pass/keys/MY.ppk "sudo -i -u root bash -c 'for curdir in \$(dir \/); do echo "fil=\$curdir" ; done'"
```

give

```
fil=
fil=
fil=
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach?  You do not need to be root to list out /.  So, no need to use sudo or ssh to root.  Also, since you really only want to get a listing of / on a remote server, why not just ssh and run the dir command?  The loop can then be local.  Something like this?

```
for curdir in $(ssh localhost dir /); do
    echo "fil=${curdir}"
done
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to run something on potentially all dirs and subdirs but am stucked at the first step

Comment: If you want to get a listing of all files and directories in a given directory, change "dir /" to "find _dir_ -print"  The find command has a lot of options to it.  So, can refine it if you wanted.

Comment: No beter result with find regarding my problem. I shurely prefer find over dir but regarding this example of what i can't do, dir is simpler

Answer (score 1):

Variables inside double quotes are expanded by the local shell, so you need to escape the dollar signs, as in your second version.

Also, double quotes inside the double quotes will terminate the string, you need to escape them as well.

BTW, there's no need to escape `/`.

```
ssh user@01.01.03.04 -i /drives/c/pass/keys/MY.ppk "sudo -i -u root bash -c 'for curdir in \$(dir /); do echo `"fil=\$curdir`" ; done'"
```

It's often easier to write using a here-doc:

```
ssh user@01.01.03.04 -i /drives/c/pass/keys/MY.ppk <<'EOF'
sudo -i -u root bash -c 'for curdir in $(dir /); do echo "fil=$curdir" ; done'
EOF
```

Putting single quotes around the `EOF` token treats the here-doc as a single-quoted string, so `$` is not treated specially.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work better. Did you escaped the double-quotes with e back-tic ?  Didn't work either using a backslash ..
did you try your command ? 
A specificity on my side: I am launching it from a MobaXterm console ...

Comment: I was missing a quote in the here-doc version. Does it work better now?

Comment: no neither here-doc nor the first one, I found the missing quote myself. did you try your versions ?

Comment: The simplest approach is to put the commands in a script on the remote host, and then do `ssh hostname /path/to/script`